# Running asynchronously tasks from a Shell in Cakephp 2.0

Tags: shell, cakephp, task

I don't have a lot of experience in Cakephp 2.0, but I want to create a shell that will call more tasks.
The idea is that I don't want to add many cron jobs but I would like to have more tasks.

The main question is if the tasks from a Shell are called asynchronously or synchronously.
It would be great if they are called asynchronously, but if not, what other solutions might there be for my problem?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

I have tested and it's very clear that tasks called in a Shell are called and executed synchronously. How can I change this? I want to start more task in the same time from the same Shell.

Comment: PHP is not multi threaded so its hardly surprising that the shell is executed synchronously. You could use a job queue to get around this issue.

Comment: That is true. I will try with a queue.

Answer (score 1):

The [Queue](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue) plugin does pretty much exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will give a try. At first look it's right what I was searching for. Thanks :)